# Which is best RAM for me to buy(since there are two different costing which another seller gave)?

Tags: laptop, memory

I have my Laptop Toshiba Satellite C640,

I got 2GB RAM and was searching for an upgrade of 4GB on Amazon. When I checked on Amazon there were many and enquired about few with Amazon. A seller shared me two other RAM which probably he/she is selling. I see a whole lot of difference in the costing

Can anyone help me what makes these two RAMs different and which is best RAM for me to buy? and how to chose the compatible one for laptops.

Though I couldn't check with Crucial software.

```
http://www.amazon.in/Samsung-PC3-10600-1333MHz-SO-DIMM-M471B5273DH0/dp/B00I2ZAEOW/ref=aag_m_pw_dp?ie=UTF8&m=A2JY2P5URJ5MSF

http://www.amazon.in/Samsung-Pc3-10600-1333mhz-So-dimm-M471b5273ch0-ch9/dp/B003XN3BZC/ref=aag_m_pw_dp?ie=UTF8&m=A2JY2P5URJ5MSF
```

And below

```
https://www.amazon.in/Transcend-1333MHZ-SO-DIMM-Laptop-Memory/dp/B00HSZFO6U

https://www.amazon.in/Transcend-4GB-DDR3L-1600-LAPTOP/dp/B00B5LOOJG
```

Comment: This is blatantly not troubleshooting or technical support. It IS blatantly "pre-purchase" - The user explicitly asks: "which is best RAM for me to buy?" What is your goal here in reading these questions so quickly that you miss this kind of thing, @ArtOfCode?

Comment: @AdamWykes I didn't miss it at all. I read that, and closed it anyway. The *primary* question here - the one in the title - is "what makes these two RAM sticks differ?", which is tech support. Additionally, the "which is best" is currently unqualified with requirements, so I'd close that as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: So you're going to close a question by an ESL user that has a few lines of bad wording in it when the thrust of the question, the "what makes these two RAM sticks differ [because I want to know which one to purchase]?" is not in dispute? OK.

Comment: @AdamWykes Stop being so pedantic. Adding "because I'm going to buy one" to an otherwise off-topic question does *not* make it on-topic.

Comment: Thank you AdamWykes. Just to clarify things @ArtOfCode. I just wanted to buy a RAM which works for my laptop for reasonable cost.  And for me the huge cost variation which different sellers shared, means a lot. And if I bought something costly assuming that the other isnt right for my laptop could have pushed me to believe that whatever each time a seller says I endup agreeing to it. Since I didnt know much about them, so its not about trouble shooting. But thanks to you both to help to improve the question

Answer (score 1):

Buy the [last](https://www.amazon.in/Transcend-4GB-DDR3L-1600-LAPTOP/dp/B00B5LOOJG) option. This RAM is faster and cheaper than the rest. The others cost more because they are being sold through other vendors who can't or don't want to compete on price. The higher price of the Samsung RAM in general can probably be attributed to compatibility; that RAM is commonly used in OEM systems and therefore will have good compatibility with many systems people own. The Transcend RAM modules on display above will also have good compatibility, but they may not be officially vetted by the OEMs, so they are less desirable to businesses and such.

In any case, the correct RAM choice for you is the last option. Even if your laptop doesn't support 1600mhz RAM, it should slow itself down to 1333mhz automatically.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering why is that cost difference and if there is anything to do with performance or durability or longevity or anything I was missing out. Since all for me seems same. And yeah there is difference of MHz but was wondering if I screw up anything

Comment: I've already answered all those questions in my answer...